# XUnit Tests Stop Running When Using EnsureDeleted() on InMemory Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, xunit, in-memory-database

During my startup of my Xunit tests I am defining dependency injection for my entity framework database context using a fake version with fake data called *FakeMyDbContext*.

```
 public void ConfigureInMemoryDatabases(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped(_ =>
        {
            var smtrOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
                               .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: $"MyDb_{Guid.NewGuid()}")
                               .Options;

            return new FakeMyDbContext(smtrOptions) as MyDbContext;
        });
    }
```

I have multiple tests that run for my service that consumes this database context, however only one ever runs. I have tracked down the issue being the following line in the Disposal of the FakeMyDbContext class:

```
  public override void Dispose()
  {
       base.Dispose();
       Database.EnsureDeleted();
  }
```

If I remove the *Database.EnsureDeleted()*, then all the tests run. If I leave it in then only one test runs. I am not sure why this would happen as I see no errors and each context instance has a unique database name (guid appended).

Comment: can you share with us a sample code for to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for my issue was that I was calling EnsureDeleted after disposing the Context.

The dispose method should look like this

```
 public override void Dispose()
  {
       Database.EnsureDeleted();
       base.Dispose();
  }
```